# regex to get string in between slash of a url

Tags: java, regex, string, split

In my website, user enters URL as http://mydomain/shirt/abc etc. I need to get `abc` as keyword (as logic given below).  It's possible with String utils. I think regex would be easier, in which I am not good.

**Java code**

```
    String testURLs[] = {"", "/" ,"/shirt", "/shirt/", "/shirt/abc", "/shirt/abc/", "/shirt/abc/xyz", "/shirt/abc?x=y", "/shirt/xyz/abc/pqr",
                            "abc/something", "/abc/some", "abc/shirt/something"};

    for(String x : testURLs){
    System.out.println(x + " --> " +getRelativeWebappURL(x));
    }

private String getAppNameFromURL(String userEnteredURL){
    String uri = userEnteredURL.replaceFirst("/shirt/","");
    int index = uri.indexOf("/");
    if(index == -1 || index == 0){
        return null;
    }
    return uri.substring(0,index);
}
```

**Output: (expected)**

```
 --> NULL
/ --> NULL
/shirt --> "" (empty string)
/shirt/ --> "" (empty string)
/shirt/abc --> abc
/shirt/abc/ --> abc
/shirt/abc/xyz --> abc
/shirt/abc?x=y --> abc
/shirt/xyz/abc/pqr --> xyz
abc/something --> NULL
/abc/some --> NULL
abc/shirt/something --> NULL
```

**Literally, the expected logic is :**

- Get the string just after `/shirt/`
- If starts with "" (empty string) - return NULL
- If starts with "/" - return NULL
- If starts with "/shirt/" - return "" (empty string)
- If starts with "/shirt" - return "" (empty string)
- If starts with "/shirt?" - return "" (empty string)
- If starts with "/shirt/?" - return "" (empty string)
- If starts with "/shirt/abc" - return abc
- If starts with "/shirt/xyz/" - return xyz
- If starts with "/shirt/xyz/abc" - return xyz

*Is there any way to do this with **regex** ?*

I tried in regex but failed!!

Comment: I cannot understand why `/shirt/?` returns empty string instead of `?`

Comment: Or http://rextester.com/JTJX22104 (too late to edit the first comment)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That's my wrong output. I will edit my question.

Comment: @VeryLazyBoy - edited question with expected output

Comment: If this is in a web server (looks like a rest  backend url), you probably should not do that parsing manually. Rather, declare the path as something like `@Path("whatever/shirt/{type}")` and then use a `@PathParam("type") String myType` parameter in the method.

Comment: @mtj - Yes it is. But the requirement is different. we have a number of requestmappers and wanted to filter centrally (not in each rest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your time to help. At last I got an exact idea from all your inputs.

Here is a **[DEMO](https://ideone.com/o41IuH)**

```
private static String getAppNameFromURL(String userEnteredURL){
    if(userEnteredURL!=null && !userEnteredURL.startsWith("/shirt")){
        return null;
    }
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^/shirt/([^?]([^\\?/]+|.*))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(userEnteredURL);
    if(m.find()){
        return m.group(1);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Output:

```
empty string-->null
/-->null
/shirt--> empty string
/shirt/--> empty string
/shirt/abc-->abc
/shirt/abc/-->abc
/shirt/abc/xyz-->abc
/shirt/abc?x=y-->abc
/shirt/xyz/abc/pqr-->xyz
abc/something-->null
/abc/some-->null
abc/shirt/something-->null
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

```
shirt\/(\w+)
```

is what you need.

```
private String getAppNameFromURL(String userEnteredURL){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("shirt\/(\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(userEnteredURL);
    if(m.find()){
        return m.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will always give you the first path parameter after shirt. If it is a word and does not start with a digit or any other non alphabetical character.

Also check this https://regexr.com/3o3jm 
You can place your expected logic here to check the regex.

Comment: Yes, this is not recommended since it omits the query string but according to his expectations this is what he wants.

Comment: The requirements changed anyway. And `"shirt\/(\w+)"` will also match `tshirt/abc`